# How could i limit the amount of displayed comments

Tags: php, mysql, comments, limit

My knowledge in PHP is very limited so i ask right away.

I'm using an on Bootstrap based site and i get initially 13 comments (max) displayed as default per post before a "read more comments" shows up.

I'm looking for a way to limit the displayed comments to 2 instead of 13 comments.

Has someone the necessary knowledge how to achieve this?

Thanks a ton in advance

````
            <li class="pp_post_comms hidden"></li>
            <?php if ($post_data['comments']) {
                foreach ($post_data['comments'] as $key => $comment) {
                    include 'comments.html';
                } } ?>

            <?php if ($post_data['votes'] > 4) { ?>
                <li class="load-comments">
                    <button onclick="load_tlp_comments(<?php echo $post_data['post_id']; ?>,this);">{{LANG show_more}} {{LANG comments}}</button>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>```
````

Answer (score 1):

in your `SQL` query add `limit 2` at the end of your query

for example

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL `LIMIT` clause. The `MySQL LIMIT` clause is used to specify the number of records to return. So in your case, you need to select only 2 out of 13 from the table `comments`. The SQL query would then look like this,

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? LIMIT 2";
```

You can read more from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp).

Comment: This answer is basically identical to the one already provided.